# files related in custom related list

Tags: files, custom, tab

I have a custom tab in opportunity object in that tab the fields are added through action layout editor, user wants to attach files in that custom component , how can i add the files in custom tab?
Reference for example in opportunity chatter is my custom component i need to add files section where user can attach files in that tab.
[image]

Comment: are you looking to add file related list as custom tab in your lightning record page?

Comment: @sanketkumar Yes, Am unable to see the files to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, You can achieve it using lightning app builder:-

- Go to your opportunity lightning record page
- click on edit page by clicking on setup icon on right top of the screen
  [image]

It will open lightning app builder where you can configure the opportunity lightning record page.

- Now, click on tab component where your details , related and activity tab exist. Add a new tab there and give a custom name

[image]

- Now, drag the related list single component and select file as related list option
  [image]

Now, save and activate the page. You can see your record page like:-

[image]

Comment: Great...Thanks alot for your help...!

Comment: Can we control the visibility of the files? i mean the files which are in custom tab should be visible only by selected profiles is that possible?